# How to pre-load all images in a div only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, preload, preloading

I have HTML that looks like this.

```
<div class='parallax'>
    <div class='slider'>
        <img src='ps1.jpg' alt=''>
        <img src='ps2.jpg' alt=''>
        <img src='ps3.jpg' alt=''>
        <img src='ps4.jpg' alt=''>
        <button id='slider-previous'>
        </button>
        <button id='slider-next'>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its for a jQuery slider that I am trying to make. The javascript is such that I don't have change it no matter how many images I add to the `<div class='slider'>`. I need to pre-load these images in a similar way. Whatever solution I could find had one of two problems.

Either it pre-loaded all the images on the webpage, including those outside of `<div class='slider'>`, or the links of the images had to be customly added to the code.

I looked into lazy-loading as an alternative (I don't need it as opposed to pre-loading) but the solutions I could find involved adding width and height attributes to the images. My div and the images have the following CSS which is absolutely essential for my slider.

```
.slider, .slider img {

width:100%;
height:auto;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}
```

I am looking for something that is somewhat like this.

```
$(function() {

$( '.slider' ).children() ..........

//OR

$( '.slider > img' ) ..........

});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please feel free to suggest edits to improve this question.

Comment: $('.slider > img')